# Chicago Author-Date: Multiple References within ONE footnote

Tags: chicago-style, zotero

I'd like a way to have a footnote with multiple references. I'm NOT looking for how to reference the same footnote multiple times which is something I've found a lot of threads on.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum¹

---
1. Smith 2020; John 2015
```

with the in-text citation looking like `\footcite{Smith2020}`.
As I use citekeys, if I include anything else in the `{}` it breaks the parsing, because it then just outputs the citekey as-is.

So far if I want to cite multiple sources in one spot, I need to use two footnotes. Chicago Author-Date says I should rather use a single one, with the sources separated with a `;`

How do I achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own problem. The solution: `\footnote`

You can use a `\cite` inside that, so that it looks like this:

`\footnote{\cite{Smith2020}; \cite{John2015}}`

That is rendered as `Smith 2020; John 2015`

Thanks :)